# How to fix unwanted ink trails when printing?

Tags: printing, printer, paper, ink

My brand new printer `Epson L120` is having the same problem as my old `Epson T10`. Here's an example:

[image]

This happens almost every time I print. Anyone knows how to I fix this?

Comment: Is the paper straight and smooth, no wrinkles no nothing? Is it standard office paper?

Comment: did paper get stuck at any time? Do you switch the printer off when not in use? Are they 'real' cartridges or cheap ones? Did you do exactly what the instructions say when changing them? Long & short of it is, ink-jets are delicate, ornery & designed to make you buy a new one every 5 minutes. Unless you print glossy photographs, get a laser. Higher outlay, spend less over 10 years.

Comment: It appears the printer and/or nozzles need to be cleaned. Excessive ink may have built up when the paper passes by. Have you cleaned the nozzles and interior of the printer?

Comment: AS Tetsujin says, if you are using refilled cartridges from other than the manufacturer, that's most likely your problem.